# Different type of questions on a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to build an app where people can come and register to some programs.

Through the application form, I need to have different kinds of questions, some text fields, some text areas, some selects, and some check boxes.

For now, I have created a model question with a content. I was thinking of creating a question type model or different models (one for each type of question) so that when creating the form, the user could choose the type of the question he wants to ask.

Here is the question model :

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :post
end
```

The question table :

```
create_table "questions", force: true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "post_id"
t.text     "content"
end
```

For now, in the _form.rb :

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |qform| %>
    <% render 'question_fields', :f => qform %>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add text area", f, :questions %></p>
<% end %>
```

_question_fields.rb :

```
    <p>
      <%= f.label :content, "Question" %>
      <%= f.text_area :content %><br>
      <%= f.check_box '_destroy' %>

    </p>
```

And the javascript functions are :

```
In application_helper.rb : 

    def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
    end

In application.js :

    function add_fields(link, association, content) {
    var new_id = new Date().getTime();
    var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
    $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
    }
```

How can it be done ?

Comment: Please be more specific, this question is too general right now.

Comment: I need the user that creates the application form to be able to choose which type of question he adds to the form each time he adds a question. I watched the nested form railscast and was thinking of using a similar link to add questions to create the form.

Comment: Good SO question should have some code or good definition of a problem at hand with info what you tried etc. You just repeated question, please give an EXAMPLE of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to develop surveys, questionnaires, quizzes.. Then please try Surveyor Gem.
It let you to generate questionaire in your application. Have a look on this :

https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor

Comment: I tried using the gem. The different types of questions are exactly the ones I want, but the thing is I won't be the only one using the app and the others won't know know how to code each quizz/questionnaires. So I need to be able to create and edit those questionnaires from a view just like some post. Do you know how can I do that ?